# Has the CVE-2019-11815 bug been patched in the kernel version 4.15.0-50-generic?

Tags: kernel, security, patch

The bug has been patched in the Linux kernel 5.0.8 version, according to the news. What about the kernel version 4.15.0-50-generic? How to check a given kernel to find out whether CVE-2019-11815 has been patched? How to patch the CVE-2019-11815 bug in Ubuntu 18.04.2 LTS with the kernel version 4.15.0-50-generic?

Comment: There is no answer to my question here: https://askubuntu.com/questions/563408/how-can-i-tell-if-a-cve-has-been-fixed-in-ubuntus-repositories
because that question is not similar to mine at all. The answers given below are much more relevant to my question. This question is about a specific kernel version. The question is unique. The accusation is unfounded because the proof not valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can see the change log of this update on
https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/4.15.0-50.54

Answer (score 1):

This affects all Linux kernels prior to 5.0.8 — therefore, it will affect version 4.15.0. It is currently being patched by the Ubuntu security team. For more details, check out the [Ubuntu CVE Tracker page on CVE-2019-11815](https://people.canonical.com/~ubuntu-security/cve/2019/CVE-2019-11815.html).

Comment: So, a fix will be available in the repositories for any package mentioned on this page, when it will state "released" instead of "needs-triage" next to the "Ubuntu 18.04 LTS (Bionic Beaver):" for that package?

Comment: I don't know when it will be fixed, but you can expect this to be patched within the next few weeks.

Comment: Maybe you can answer this too? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1142525/config-regex-for-fail2ban-to-catch-pregreeters-in-mail-log

Answer (score 1):

This question has been nagging me for a long time: [How do I map Linux Kernels to Ubuntu Kernels?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1010811/how-do-i-map-linux-kernels-to-ubuntu-kernels) Unfortunately I'm no closer today to that answer than I was back then.

So below is my best guess for you.

---

Go to: https://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline and sort by date by clicking column header. Sort again for descending order and scroll until you see `5.0.8`:

[image: mainline kernel after 5.0.8.png]

- Everything released after `5.0.8` will presumably have **CVE-2019-11815** patch applied.
- `5.0.8` was compiled on the Ubuntu Kernel Farm on April 15, 2019.
- Personally I've downloaded and installed `4.14.114` LTS kernel compiled on April 27, 2019 so it would have the patch applied.

So the big question is what date was your kernel `4.15.0-50` compiled?

Look in `/boot` directory at my `4.14.114` as an example:

```
$ ll /boot/*4.14.114*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   213788 Apr 27 04:08 /boot/config-4.14.114-0414114-generic
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 63203180 Apr 29 19:43 /boot/initrd.img-4.14.114-0414114-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  3983979 Apr 27 04:08 /boot/System.map-4.14.114-0414114-generic
-rw------- 1 root root  8681248 May 12 10:37 /boot/vmlinuz-4.14.114-0414114-generic
```

Firstly ignore `/boot/vmlinuz-4.14.114-0414114-generic` because my grub boot flags the last time each kernel was booted so the date May 12 2019 is bogus for your purpose.

The file `/boot/vmlinuz-4.14.114-0414114-generic` or `/boot/System.map-4.14.114-0414114-generic` ***should*** tell you the time your kernel was released. If after April 15, 2019 you ***should*** have the desired patch applied.

The remaining file `/boot/initrd.img-4.14.114-0414114-generic` should be the date the kernel was installed on your system.

Of course you will replace `4.14.114` above with `4.15.0`!!!

There is also a [publication](https://people.canonical.com/~kernel/info/kernel-version-map.html) linking Ubuntu kernel release numbers to stable Linux kernel release numbers but I find it confusing. If you figure it out please post an answer.

Comment: Have you written a regex for a fail2ban config file? https://askubuntu.com/questions/1142525/config-regex-for-fail2ban-to-catch-pregreeters-in-mail-log

Comment: @viDim Unfortunately I'm not that good with Regex yet. Plus I'm sorry to say I really don't understand what the link is asking...

Comment: I edited the question about regex. Maybe somebody knows how to write regex for fail2ban config files. https://askubuntu.com/questions/1142525/regex-for-fail2ban-config-file-to-match-pregreet-lines-in-mail-log

Comment: I don't use `fail2ban` nor do I have a Web Server so wouldn't have a clue if there was a better way to solve your problem.